# Angular form validation in IE

Tags: validation, angularjs

I'm trying to get Angular form validation working in ie8. Here is my code:

```
      <form id="contact-form" name="cform" target="_blank"  >
          <div class="left">
              <div>
                 <div class="group">
                    <label for="firstname">First Name <span class="asterisk">*</span></label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" data-ng-model="firstname" required />
                    <span class="error" data-ng-show="cform.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
                </div>
                <div class="group">
                    <label for="lastname">Last Name <span class="asterisk">*</span></label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" data-ng-model="lastname" required />
                    <span class="error" data-ng-show="cform.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <div class="group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span></label><br />
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" data-ng-model="email" required />
                    <span class="error" data-ng-show="cform.email.$error.email">Required!</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <div class="group">      
                      <label for="phone">Primary Phone Number <span class="asterisk">*</span></label><br />
                      <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" data-ng-model="phone" required />
                      <span class="error" data-ng-show="cform.input.$error.required">Required!</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="group">
                      <label for="-secondary-phone">Secondary Phone Number</label><br />
                      <input type="text" name="secondary-phone" id="secondary-phone" />
                  </div>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
              <div class="group">
                  <label for="message">Your Message</label><br />
                  <textarea id="message"></textarea>
              </div><br />
              <input type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" class="button">
          </div>
      </form>
```

This works in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE8 no validation errors are triggered. Anyone know what the issue might be?

Thanks.

UPDATE: This seems to be a problem in all versions of IE. {{cform.input.$error}} and {{cform.input}} don't show output in any browser.

Comment: I have no idea what's going on, even jsfiddle doesn't work in IE8 (surprise, surprise!) but firstly try to see if cform.input.$error exists. You can use the construction {{cform.input.$error}} or start from {{cform.input}}.

Comment: @Kate {{Cform.input.$error}} and {{cform.input}} don't display anything even on Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="group">
                <label for="firstname">First Name <span class="asterisk">*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" data-ng-model="firstname" ng-required="true" />
                <span class="error" data-ng-show="cform.firstname.$error.required  && cform.firstname.$dirty">Required!</span>
            </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ie 8 does not support html 5 ,Angular is using html 5 , Do the work around to get angular working on IE and then use the pattern because you cant use the html 5 element

Comment: Ie8 does not support <input type="email">